# ffmpeg fails on too bad TS stream

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg stops transcode *.ts file if some bad TS packets in it.

Any bad TS packet has TEI flag signed (Transport Error Indicator).

Whow to drive ffmpeg to ignor bad TS backets?

Answer (score 0):

Have find an answer.  FFMpeg doesn’t care about transport much and there could be sort of transport error that ffmpeg crash. Take care on transport error correction on your own.